# Unordered X Y coordinate pairs + Concentration contourplot

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I have 2 vectors, X and Y, corresponding to a list of unordered coordinates, and a corresponding concentration vector C for each point.

I'd like to plot this on a structured grid as a 2D contour plot.

```
scatter3(X,Y,C,[],C);
```

gives me what I want visually, but I'm looking for 2D contours, i.e. `pcolor`. Is there an easy solution like griddata or trigriddata?

EDIT: Ok, so `scatter3(X,Y,C,[],C); view([0 90])´ is the correct visual.
TriScatteredInterp works nicely for a rectangle. But what about an irregular shape like a map? :=)

`F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,C);`
   `ty=0:0.005:0.284;`
   `tx=0:0.005:0.65;`
   `[qx,qy] = meshgrid(tx,ty);`
   `qC = F(qx,qy);`
   `pcolor(qx,qy,qC);`

EXAMPLE: (X=width coordinate , Y= height coordinate, C= concentration of pollutant)

```
X    Y    C
0.1  0.0  5
0.1  0.1  10
0.1  0.21 5
0.2  0.1  4
0.2  0.3  1
0.2  0.5  2
0.2  0.51 7
0.3  0.15 4
0.3  0.36 6
0.3  0.5  3
0.3  0.52 7

scatter3(X,Y,C,[],C,'filled');      %individual plotting of X,Y pairs and colors=C
view([0 90])                        %see only XY and Z becomes flat
```

Imagine we had 10000 XY pairs so `scatter3` produces almost an `image` but without interpolation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Give an example

Comment: Ok, so scatter3(X,Y,C,[],C); view([0 90]) is the correct visual.


F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,C);


ty=0:0.005:0.284;
tx=0:0.005:0.65;
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(tx,ty);
qC = F(qx,qy);
mesh(qx,qy,qC);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can use `contour(X,Y,Z)`

EDIT: You can use `imagesc` with a matrix that you make yourself. So if your `x` and `y` values are in a reasonable range you can just start with:

```
I = zeros(max(x), max(y));
for d = 1: length(x),
    I(x(d),y(d)) = z(d);
end
imagesc(I);
```

Comment: Eg. X Y are a cloud of coordinates of points. Each pair has a concentration C. Fine up to there. They correspond to lines on a plane, but the lines are stacked ontop of each other in X and Y.  Reshape doesn't work because there are an unknown number of samples in each line.  I'd like to upload a picture but it says because I'm new I can't.  Ideally I'd like to use hist3 but that only gives me the density of the points in a particular bins.  I must be missing something.  Can I upload a picture here being a noobie?

Comment: @Ali `countour` requires `Z` to be a two-dimensional matrix, not a one-dimensional vector, which `C` seems to be according to the question.

Comment: Thanks Ali.  A couple of things though,  I have an irregular shape like a river for example and I don't know a priori how many divisions are in the y direction because these are unevenly spaced.  What do you think?

Comment: I think as far as the ranges of `x` and `y` fall within MATLAB memory limits on your machine you should be fine. There is no assumption of regular shape here. Also you can give small examples of `x`, `y`, `z` to us so that we can understand better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ali Hopefully that example illustrates the point (no pun intended) a bit better.